# Type 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'WCSessionDelegate' calls infinity times

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit

I wan't to pair iphone application with AppleWatch , when i'm implement to AppDelegate a WCSession delegate , they always show to me error "Type 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'WCSessionDelegate'" But i'm added the function of this protocol 
Here i'm implement code of protocol

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
            let wcsession = WCSession.default
            wcsession.delegate = self
            wcsession.activate()
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1wlx.png)

Comment: It seems like some delegate methods are missing, just click `Fix` for `add protocol stub`, then clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

Below the **AppDelegate** class add this extension that confirm to the delegate protocol and use it subs

```
extension AppDelegate: WCSessionDelegate { 
//use WCSessionDelegate functions
}
```

Comment: you need to add the subs .. there are some required functions you need to override to be able to correctly confirm to the delegate .. click fix

Answer (score 0):

Add below methods for `WCSessionDelegate`

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {

}

func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {

}

func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {

}
```

This are required methods for `WCSessionDelegate`

And just clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: exactly, you should be able to click Fix, on the error and it auto generate them for you

Comment: i click this , then they add to me missed function  , but error don't vanishes

Comment: Can you just build it again with command + B key if you have same functions added as I showed in answer

Comment: I clean the project and rebuild , but nothing changed , so strange :|